# Camera X CameraSelector issue at change Front to Back camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

Everything is working fine but when I change the camera from Front to Back at that time my device home screen show in between. Here is the GIF please check.

[image]

Here is what I use for the camera selector:

```
iv_flip_camera.setSafeOnClickListener {
            this@HomeActivity.runOnUiThread {
                cameraSelector = if (cameraSelector == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA) {
                    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
                } else {
                    CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
                }

                startCamera()
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the device model? Is it reproducible on other devices? Can you reproduce this with https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic?

Comment: This issue comes in all devices. In which device I tested is Oneplus 6, Oneplus 8, realme 7, Motorola, redmi. @Xi张熹

Comment: Then it's probably just because the way your code is written. Are you using PreviewView? Could you add a black background during camera switch? For PreviewView, see github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

Comment: Yes, Yesterday I set black background during the switch camera. Inspired by Oneplus device camera :). Thanks @Xi张熹